# Upload images from Raspberry pi to Dropbox using python 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cloud, dropbox

This project is taking pictures for the sky and then it's going to mask the clouds, so there will be two pictures, one is the original and the other is the masked one.

I just want to upload every picture taken by the camera pi to Dropbox.

Here is the main code:

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from makebinary import makebinary
import dropbox


# enable switching to picamera from commandline call (pass in 'picamera')
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    capture_method = 'gphoto'
else:
    capture_method = sys.argv[1]

basedir = '/home/pi/Pictures'
# The radius in pixels of the fisheye lens area, set to None if no fisheye lens
fisheye_radius = None

# capture an image with the specified method
if capture_method.lower() == 'gphoto':
    import subprocess
    out = subprocess.check_output(['gphoto2', '--capture-image-and-download'])
    for line in out.split('\n'):
        if 'Saving file as' in line:
            file = line.split(' ')[3]
            break
    else:
        raise Exception('GPhoto image capture and save unsuccessful.')
elif capture_method.lower() == 'picamera':
    from picamera import PiCamera
    from time import sleep

    # open the camera and take the latest image
    file = 'latest.jpg'
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(2)             # wait for the camera to initialise
    camera.capture(file) # capture and save an image to 'file'
else:
    raise Exception("Invalid capture method {}. Use 'gphoto' or 'picamera'."
                    .format(capture_method))

# capture the timestamp
now = datetime.now()
# create the relevant folders if they don't already exist
os.makedirs(basedir + now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"), exist_ok=True)

# move the new image to within its relevant folder with a timestamped filename
new_file = basedir + now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.jpg")
os.rename(file, new_file)

# process as desired (compute cloud coverage and mask image)
makebinary(new_file, fisheye_radius)
```

So far I have tried this code:

```
with open(new_file, 'rb') as f:
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('Token)
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(),'/image.jpg')
f.close()
```

But I'm just getting one image to be uploaded in the Dropbox and when I try again to run the code again I get this error which basically means it's already their in the dropbox. But what I really want is to upload the new pictures every time I run the main code.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/DIY-sky-imager/capture_image.py", line 56, in <module>
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(),'/image.jpg')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 2762, in files_upload
    f,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 340, in request
    user_message_locale)
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('65464abaadc57d6d7862377638810', UploadError('path', UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError('conflict', WriteConflictError('file', None)), upload_session_id='AAAABR7Z7FHkkk9vyiuyw')))
```

Comment: Save now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.jpg") as variable and use as upload filename!

Comment: @ jiho lee , Sorry if I did not get you correctly.. but isn't it already saved as "new_file" in my main code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [the `files_upload` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload) in the Dropbox Python SDK, you specify where you want to upload via the value you supply to the `path` parameter.

A `path/conflict/file` [error when uploading to Dropbox indicates that the upload failed because "There’s a file in the way"](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.WriteConflictError).

Looking at your code, this seems expected in this case since you're always specifying the value `'/image.jpg'`, so after the first successful call, there will already be a file there.

You should instead change your code to use a different `path` for each different file.

Comment: Thanks , But I don't want to make it manually like every time I run that code I have to make new path...  but what I want is  just to save pictures directly when I run the code. My pi camera is taking picture and saves it in a path every time I run the code..

Comment: @wrongpath You don't need to set the value manually each time. You can have your code dynamically produce a unique filename instead of just `'/image.jpg'`. For example, the author of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529331/upload-images-from-raspberry-pi-to-dropbox-using-python-3/64539228?noredirect=1#comment114101578_64529331) suggested using the timestamp in the filename.

Comment: May I know if this API is limited per day? or it's unlimited API

Comment: Also the API is changing every day why? I want to make it the same every time I run the code.

Comment: @wrongpath The Dropbox API does have a rate limiting system, but you don't seem to be running in to any rate limits here. Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "the API is changing every day why?". Your code seems to be working as expected, since you're always passing up the same `path` value, which will cause you to run in to this `path/conflict/file` error. You should instead use a variable for that so you can use a different `path` to identify different files. If you're having trouble with something else, open a new post with the details.